# Adding jquery in drupal 7 module

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have a problem with jquery in my module of drupal 7 .this is how I add them in my .module code

```
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'sync') . '/js/Syncronization.js', 'module', 'footer');
```

I am pretty sure my js code is correct, cause it works fine in Drupal 6, but in 7 - no. please help...

Answer (score 0):

[`drupal_add_js()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) only takes 2 arguments in Drupal 7:

```
$path = drupal_get_path('module', 'sync') . '/js/Syncronization.js';
drupal_add_js($path, array('scope' => 'footer'));
```

Answer (score 0):

It is true that drupal_add_js does not take the third argument, however in PHP passing an extra argument won't cause anything to misbehave.  It is more likely that you need to update your js/Syncronization.js for drupal 7.  The way you set drupal behaviors has changed in D7.

You used to set

Drupal.behaviors = function () { ....

but now you set

Drupal.behaviors = { attach : function () { ....

Please review

http://drupal.org/node/756722

Answer (score -2):

If you want to add the js on a form, you need to use $form['#attached']['js'][] otherwise, add the js in the .info file of you current theme. drupal_add_js does not work especially in hook_form_alter!